# Propensity scores with multiple treatments, and a multinomial outcome in R

Tags: r, propensity-scores

I am using [mnsp](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/twang/vignettes/mnps.pdf) function to estimate propensity scores for multiple treatments. Then, I generate weights using the survey package, but I cannot use svyglm to estimate my treatment effects because my outcome is not binary or numeric.

My outcome variable has 3 categories, therefore I want to estimate relative risk ratios by running a multinomial logistic model. However, survey package does not allow multinomial logit. It seems like mlogit function allows weights. Would it be fine to just plug in the weights I derived from the get.weights function?

I am a novice in R, any recommendations are welcome. Here is my R code:

```
DAT <-read.delim("DAT.txt", header=TRUE)
library(twang)
set.seed(1)
mnps.DAT <- mnps(city_ber ~ age + unemplyd + student + moedum + faedum,
                data = TIES, estimand = "ATE", verbose = FALSE,
               stop.method = c("es.mean", "ks.mean"),
                n.trees = 10000)
#Diagnostics
plot(mnps.DAT, plots = 1)
plot(mnps.DAT, plots = 2)
plot(mnps.DAT, plots = 3, pairwiseMax = FALSE, figureRows = 3)
means.table(mnps.DAT, stop.method = "es.mean", digits = 3)

#Generating Weights
require(survey)
DAT$w <- get.weights(mnps.DAT, stop.method = "es.mean")
    design.mnps <- svydesign(ids=~1, weights=~w, data=DAT)
    summary(DAT$w)

#Outcome analysis?
```

Comment: So I actually asked this question to the team working on twang at Rand Corporation. They told me it is better to continue the analysis using another software that has better coverage of models with survey weights (e.g, Stata) after I generate my weights in R.